# How to convert multi dimensional array in JSON as separate columns in pandas

Tags: json, pandas, multidimensional-array, normalize

I have a DB collection consisting of nested strings . I am trying to convert the contents under "status" column as separate columns against each order ID in order to track the time taken from "order confirmed" to "pick up confirmed". The string looks as follows:

[image]

I have tried the same using

```
xyz_db= db.logisticsOrders -------------------------(DB collection)
df =pd.DataFrame(list(xyz_db.find()))   ------------(JSON to dataframe)
```

Using normalize :

```
parse1=pd.json_normalize(df['status'])
```

It works fine in case of non nested arrays. But status being a nested array the output is as follows:

[image]

Using for :

```
data = df[['orderid','status']]
data =  list(data['status'])

dfy = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['statuscode','statusname','laststatusupdatedon'])

for i in range(0, len(data)):
    result = data[i]
    dfy.loc[i] = [data[i][0],data[i][0],data[i][0],data[i][0]]
```

It gives the result in form of appended rows which is not the format i am trying to achieve

The output I am trying to get is :

[image]

Please help out!!

Answer (score 0):

i share you which i used json read, maybe help you:

you can  use two and more list

```
def jsonify(z):
    genr = []
    if z==z and z is not None:
        z = eval(z)
        if type(z) in (dict, list, tuple):
            for dic in z:
                for key, val in dic.items():
                    if key == "name":
                        genr.append(val)

        else:
            return None
    else:
        return None
    return genr
    

top_genr['genres_N']=top_genr['genres'].apply(jsonify)
```